# Кастомный чекбокс Android

Tags: java, android, checkbox, style

Доброго времени суток! Возник следующий вопрос:

как сделать кастомный чекбокс в андроиде? Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889729/change-checkbox-background-color-in-android) есть пример кастомизации. Все работает, но проблема в том что при создании такого кастомного чекбокса у него пропадает галка. А можно ли (и если да то как) кастомизировать чекбокс с галкой? Может примеры какие есть? Я бы хотел получить такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что именно в нем необходимо кастомизировать?

Answer (score 7):

Рисуете две картинки - отмеченный чекбокс (checked.png) и не отмеченный (unchecked.png) - хоть с "галкой" , хоть с чем угодно.
Чекбокс будет выглядеть точно так , как вы его нарисуете , "галка" - это не какой то отдельный элемент , она просто нарисована со всем остальным фоном вместе.

делаешь селектор и помещаешь в *res/drawable* (checkbox_selector.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checked"/>
   <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked" />
  </selector>
```

назначаешь в атрибутах чекбокса на разметке этот селектор:

```
<CheckBox
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
  android:text="CheckBox" />
```