# Наложить png на shape

Tags: java, android, checkbox

Доброго времени суток! Я пытаюсь сделать кастомный чекбокс. В [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/419824/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81-android)
мне посоветовали что для этого нужно сделать два изображения - надатый и ненажатый чекбокс и вставлять их вместо дефолтного изображения. У меня есть изображение галки и я бы хотел наложить это изображение на shape чтобы не рисовать в фотошопе еще и фон для чекбокса. Можно ли как-то наложить png на shape в андроид и если да то как? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Документация](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList).
В верхний слой нужно поместить изображение галки, в нижний слой поместить фон. И пользоваться как обычным drawable.