# Кастомный вертикальный switch

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Понадобилось сделать вертикальный `switch`, в интернете насчет этого ничего нет, по крайней мере не нашел, есть варианты с `ToggleButton` и `ImageButton`, но мне это не очень подходит, потому что переключение только при нажатии, реализация через `OnTouchListener` тоже не очень устраивает.

В общем может есть библиотека с помощью  которой можно реализовать вертикальный `switch`?

Comment: Ели бы он был маленького размера я бы не заморачивался, а так как он будет большим, явно его будут включать свайпом.

Comment: Это просто две картинки  в селекторе (положение включено и положение выключено), вы можете нарисовать там все, что угодно, хоть диагональный свитч. Смотрите например [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419828/177345) по чекбоксам - принцип тот же.

Comment: В таком варианте свайп не будет работать. На данный момент у меня так и реализовано, с помощью ImageButton.

Comment: Но `Switch` и так реагирует на свайп (его можно двигать пальцем), с чего вы взяли, что это не будет работать? Хотя в вашем случае еще нужно будет переопределить метод `onTouch()` класса `Switch`, чтобы он реагировал на вертикальный, а не горизонтальный свайп (конкретно видимо логику кейса  [TOUCH_MODE_DRAGGING](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/widget/Switch.java#439)) и `onDraw()`, еще [кастомизировать сам свитч](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10140801). Готового решения скорее всего нет, нужно делать свой класс

Comment: @pavlofff , Спасибо, да, готового решения нету, попробую как Вы рекомендуете.