# Кастомизация switch button android

Tags: java, android, ui

Как сделать такую кнопку в Android?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это какой-то вид Switch?

Comment: Если вам не нужна анимация какая-то, то лучше создать `ImageView` и менять картинки. Или создать два состояния как два `layout`, поместить их в `FrameLayout` и так же показывать разные картинки.

Comment: Ручками, и конечно же поиском по всеми любимому [how-to-custom-switch-button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358822/how-to-custom-switch-button)

Comment: самый обычный `Switch` или `ToggleButton` с кастомным фоном

Comment: Пример по [кастомизации CheckBox](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419828/177345), здесь то же самое