# Сравнение картинки в ImageView и картинки из ресурсов

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-imageview

Подскажите пожалуйста. Передо мной стоит задача динамически менять картинку при нажатии на ImageView. Это по сути кнопка лайков. Нажал один раз, картинка поменялась на лайк, нажал другой  раз, картинка поменялась на unlike и так до бесконечности. Изначально в imageView при инициализации сетится картинка из ресурсов. Поэтому я решил, что необходимо сравнивать картинку в ImageView и картинку из ресурсов.
Решаю так:

```
if (imageViewLike.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_18dp).getConstantState())){
                    imageViewLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_18dp);
                } else {imageViewLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_18dp);
                }
```

в версии 4.1.1 работает в 5.1 нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Берете любой стандартный виджет Android с двумя состояниями (`Checkbox`, `ToggleButton`, `Switch`, `RadioButton` - в вашем случае удобнее первый) и [кастомизируете его](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419828/177345) таким образом, что состояние "включено" (отмечено) - изображение лайк, состояние "выключено" (не отмечено) - дизлайк. Все, он будет переключаться при нажатии (текст нужно сделать пустой строкой, если вам не нужна подпись).

Узнать текущее состояние можно методом [`isCheced()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#isChecked()), принудительно установить состояние методом [`setChecked()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setChecked(boolean))/ В обоих случаях значение `true` будет соотвествовать лайку, `false` - дизлайку.