# кастомные radiobuttons

Tags: android, view, android-customview

Здравствуйте! никак не могу найти решение для кастомизации моих radiobuttons...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот так они должны выглядеть... как поменять цвет точечки разобрался, а как сделать кординально разные цвета у контура и у button, поменять фон точечки и изменить размер - ни одного примера не нашёл...
Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли это. Если да - какие есть решения???
Спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419828/177345 - здесь чекбоксы, но радибатоны то же самое. Отмеченное и неотмеченное состояние - просто картинка, как нарисуете, так и будет выглядеть.

Comment: спасибо за ответ....