# Создать кастомный чекбокс

Tags: android, xml, android-style

Можете подсказать/поделиться кодом, как сделать такой **чекбокс**?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю сам, ничерта не получается(недавно в android). Я так понимаю, что нужно создать свой стиль, унаследованный от

`Base.Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.CheckBox`

чтобы потом указать в нём фоном свой селектор типо

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#1E90FF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

по логике вроде так, только это пока что не работает от слова совсем.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419828/177345

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте в папке `res/drawable` файл `checkbox_selector.xml`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_checked="false">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <size android:width="15dp" android:height="15dp" />
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#1e90ff" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_checked="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item android:width="10dp" android:height="10dp" //Для API 23+
              android:bottom="5dp" android:top="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:left="5dp" //Для API до 23
            android:gravity="center">
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <size android:width="10dp" android:height="10dp" />
                <solid android:color="#1e90ff" />
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item android:width="15dp" android:height="15dp">
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <size android:width="15dp" android:height="15dp" />
                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#1e90ff" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
</selector>
```

В самом `checkbox` пропишите такой атрибут:

```
android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
```

Comment: Всё сделал, но ваш чекбокс невидим. В визуальном редакторе видно, что атрибут `android:button` сжимает элемент в точку. А с `style` и `android:background` решение не работает. API 23, поэтому в `checkbox_on_background.xml` оставил только `android:height="10dp"` и `android:width="10dp"`

Comment: добавил всё в один файл `checkbox_selector.xml`, проверил, у меня работает