# Модификация switch в API 25

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать такой ползунок в API 25?
`Switch` изменили и он стал круглым, как его преобразовать в такой вид я так и не нашел.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/933953/Создать-кастомный-чекбокс/933959#933959 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/419824/Кастомный-чекбокс-android/419828#419828